# Change css using jquery only for string beginning with specific character

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change css for strings that occur in page text only if they start with #

i.e. if #1 is typed then auto renders with specific css tag

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this onchange() event for your  div or text area

```
if ($(#id).text().trim().charAt(0) == "#")
    your logic goes here
```